# web img tag load image block scrollbar and the main thread. How to resolve for UX

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a list of products when enter this page. Will get a list of product and product image, this image is larget, but request time is not a problem. And I will set this image like Thumbnail, then the problem happened when a list of image loading on img tag, the scrollbar will be blocked.

The problems:

1. image have been load(not Http request) and append image to DOM will block the main thread?
2. How to solve this problem besides Compresse the picture at the backend?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much prioritiy you want to give images you could do something like load the html tag with:

```html
<img data-unloaded_src="[your image location]" scr="">
```

Then load the image later on with something like

```js
window.requestIdleCallback(function(){
    var all_images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for(var i = 0; i < all_images.length; i++){
        if(all_images[i].dataset.unloaded_src){
            all_images[i].src = all_images[i].dataset.unloaded_src;
        }
    }
});
```

Your milage will vary using requestIdleCallback. You might want to just trigger it on dom content loaded or something? It seems odd that any image loading would lock up the scroll bar...